# How do we know that an integral is unsolvable?

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations, multivariable-calculus

I am currently learning intro differential equations. I am confused how one *knows* that an ODE will not be solvable. It seems that for the most part, the equations becomes "unsolvable" about halfway through the work, once you hit an impossible integral. For example, in my textbook, they are showing how using the integrating factor technique can go wrong, and end up with this:

$e^{-t^3/3}y = \int{e^{-t^3/3}(t-1)dt}$

They then say that we are stuck here, because the integral on the right hand side of the equation is no expressible in terms of familiar functions (sin, cos, ln, etc...)

My question is, how does one *know* that this won't be expressible in familiar functions? Do you just have to "try it", until you learn from experience of "trying it" what will and won't work (i.e. you simply can visually recognize from experience that you won't be able to evaluate the integral)? Or is there something inherent to the right hand side in this example that can make you *certain* there won't be a solution, without trying it?

That is my main question, but I also am wondering; if this particular solution, which doesn't seem like it should be so overly complicated, cannot be expressed in terms of familiar functions, why haven't more "standard" functions been invented over the past 300 years? Are there actually more "exotic" functions that *can* describe the solution?

Comment: [This](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Risch_algorithm) is the theoretical solution. ​ (I don't know how it's done in practice.) ​ ​ ​ ​

Comment: You want to look into the Risch Algorithm, this can determine what functions have closed form antiderivatives.  Its a bit like Galois theory in the sense it can show that some functions have no antiderivative which can be computed from the various transformation of simple functions.  I think its fair to say that there are more functions which have no antiderivative than which have one, in fact having an antiderivative is kinda uncommon and special!!

Comment: I don't fully understand the linked article and would have to do more research, but thanks for the direction. However, doesn't it say that this method only determines _whether or not_ a integral will have a solution expressed in familiar functions? If not, it still cannot actually calculate it?

Comment: See also [Liouville's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville's_theorem_(differential_algebra)).

Comment: @Lucian It seems that "unfarmiliar" functions are used in complicated integration (such as the [error function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Error_function)). But these unfamiliar functions seem to be _defined_ by the integral of a familiar function! Isn't that a circular definition? How does a computer (or human) plot that?

Comment: That well may be, mathematicians are inclined to prove that a solution exists for a problem, but don't have a clue on how to find it.

Comment: @user247608 So in these cases, we rely on numeric and geometric "solutions" as our only option? It seems strange to me that functions don't exist to express nearly anything. I mean, $sin$, $cos$, and $ln$ never existed before being invented. Shouldn't a sufficiently complicated series be able to describe almost anything?

Comment: Integrals can be calculated numerically (tabulated) by several means so the definition isn't circular.  Only a relative handful of functions are defined this way, often other integrals can be transformed into one of the tabulated types.  The remainder aren't interesting enough to be tabulated ;p)

Comment: No. Functions which can be approximated by power series are too well behaved, like they are continuous and have well defined deriviates almost everywhere.  Some functions are unbelievably naughty, well in fact, almost all functions are unbelievably naughty, we just like to play with the nice ones.

Comment: @user247608 I see, thank you. Also, what do you mean by "tabulated"

Comment: Taking anti-derivatives often takes you out of a given field of functions. The logarithm , the anti-derivative of 1/x, cannot be expressed in rational functions, even allowing fractional roots and (local) inverses. So we give it a name,  and discover its properties. Proving that a given anti-derivative does not belong to a given class of functions is usually far from trivial.

Comment: @user254665 Are you saying that the logarithm doesn't have an explicit definition using rational functions? How is it ever "calculated" then? By using purely numerical methods?

Comment: "Tabulated" as in put into a table - we used to have printed tables of functions like the log, sin, cos etc in the back of our textbooks, so if you needed the log of 3.14159 you'd have to look it up in the table.   I guess now you can punch it into your iphone and it'll be calculated from a series approximation, still - each entry in the table we used to have had to be calculated from some approximation.

Comment: In response to jphollowed's response to my previous comment :Yes of course. And you can't express $\sqrt x$ in terms of finitely many rational functions either. For $|x|<1$ we have $ \log (1+x)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} (-1)^{n+1}x^n/n.$ E.g. $\log 2=-\log (1-1/2)=2^{-1}+2^{-2}/2+2^{-3}/3+...$. To compute $\sqrt 3,$ let $x_1=1$ and $x_{n+1}=(x_n+3/x_n)/2,$ converging rapidly to $\sqrt 3.$

Comment: Functions like logarithms cannot be expressed as rational functions - not exactly anyway -  the logarithm needs a infinite number of terms in its power series expansion, the rational functions only have a finite number, so there's always going to be a mismatch - be it vanishingly small with more terms. (sorry user 254665 I thought that question was directed at me user247608!!)